# No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.bat() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Job DSL script that creates a new Freestyle job. The job should have active choice parameters for selecting options and batch commands need to be executed as part of the job and create a txt file of selected parameters. However, I am encountering an error while executing the batch commands.

Here is my DSL script:

```
job('Options_Selection_JobDSL') {
    parameters {
        activeChoiceParam('select_checkboxs') {
            description('Selection of Options')
            filterable()
            choiceType('CHECKBOX')
            groovyScript {
                    script('return ["Option_1","Option_2","Option_3"]')
                fallbackScript('"fallback choice"')
            }
        }
    }
    steps{
        bat """echo %select_checkboxs% > C:\\projects\\tools\\main_ci-cd\\selected_checkboxs.txt"""
    }
}
```

while executing this DSL

`ERROR: No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.bat() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values`

The job should have active choice parameters for selecting options and batch commands need to be executed as part of the job and create a txt file of selected parameters by exeuting `bat` command in jobdsl.

Comment: Are you using a plugin or library with a conflicting definition for the `bat` step?

Comment: No sure I am using JobDSL for creating this job.